# MVC Controller The server was not found or not accessible

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I create a new MVC web project in Visual Studio 2015, add a new class, and attach a MVC 5 Controller with Entity Framework to it. But when I run the index file(the one which will display a list of items I have in that class database), It gives the error as shown below.How to solve this problem? I don't know what to do since I am very new to ASP.NET-MVC and I thought the controller will handle those things for me.

EDIT: I tried the same thing in Visual Studio 2013 and it comes out fine.

EDIT2: Now I run the same program in  Visual Studio 2015 again and it works. What da...

[image]

Comment: Make sure your connection string is correct.

Comment: @SergeyKolodiy How to check?

Comment: Your Web.Config has the connection strings that you need verify.

Comment: In the root of your project there should be a Web.config file which contains configuration settings for the project. You're looking for the connection string for the WebApplication3Context, which should be in the [connectionStrings section](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bf7sd233(v=vs.85).aspx), as something like `<add name="WebApplication3Context" connectionString="..." .../>` The connection string is the value for the connectionString attribute of that add tag.

Comment: @Gavin.Paolucci.Kleinow My connection string for `DefaultConnection` is `Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-WebApplication3-20150819093905.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-WebApplication3-20150819093905;Integrated Security=True` and `Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB; Initial Catalog=WebApplication3Context-20150819214107; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True; AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|WebApplication3Context-20150819214107.mdf` for `WebApplication3Context`.

Comment: Do you have a connection string for WebApplication3Context? Are you sure that DefaultConnection is being used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chenge your connection to :

```
Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=aspnet-WebApplication3-20150819093905;Integrated Security=True;
```

(.) in Data Source mean is local server.

the following link help you to create connection string :

http://www.connectionstrings.com/